# Multiple linear regression - correlation coefficient

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression

I am searching for the formula to calculate the correlation coefficient in case of multiple linear regression.

I have 2 independent variables $X1$ and $X2$, and 1 dependent variable $Y$. I want to study whether there is correlation between the 3 parameters.

The model is

$$ Y = aX1 + bX2 + c $$

I was able to calculate $a$, $b$, and $c$. Now I need to 'analyze' whether there is a correlation. In case of linear regression $x$ and $y$, the formula is:

$$ r = \frac{cov(x,y)}{ \sqrt{var(x)var(y)} } $$

What is the formula in case of $x1$, $x2$, and $y$.

Is it called multiple correlation?

Comment: @whuber, I have read this link http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linmult.htm. They seem to calculate Rsquared. But the formula is not there. Can you please give me hints or direct me?

Comment: @whuber, is `multiple correlation` the term word I am looking for?

Comment: I don't know.  What are you trying to learn or characterize about the regression?  "A correlation" could mean many things and can be measured in many ways: through $R^2$, through a singular value decomposition or principal components analysis, though the determinant of a covariance matrix, and many other things.

Comment: @whuber, I want to study whether $x1$ and $x2$ can explain $y$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351200/multiple-correlation-coefficient-with-three-or-more-independent-variables/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Multiple correlation` IS what you are looking for. It is a measure of how well the dependent variable can be predicted by a set of independent variables. The symbol is $R$ and it should be $R>0$.

Assuming your independent variables are $x$ and $y$. The dependent variables is $z$, then the `multiple correlation coefficient` is given by

$$ R_{z,xy} = \sqrt{  \frac{r_{xz}^2 + r_{yz}^2 - 2r_{xz}r_{yz}r_{xy} }{ 1-r_{xy}^2 }   }$$

where $r_{xz}$, $r_{yz}$, and $r_{xy}$ are defined as the correlation coefficient between 2 variables. The formula to each is the one you stated above.

Comment: What if I want to study the effect of $x1$ on $y$ (without taking into account $x2$) and then study the effect of $x2$ on $y$ (without taking into account the effect of $x1$). Is it possible?

Comment: Those two studies are called *simple regression.*  There are many examples of its theory, output, and interpretation on this site.

Comment: @whuber, the OP might also be interested in the `partial correlation` and/or the `semi-partial correlation`. In his case, this approach or the `simple regression` approach should give the same results since he's dealing with only 2 independent variables. Hence, holding one as a constant reduces to the simple regression form. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The simple (univariate) regression coefficients will differ from the multivariate coefficients when there are two or more regressors that are not orthogonal.  The simple correlation coefficients will also differ from the partial correlation coefficients in those cases.

Comment: @whuber, then which one do you suggest I use? The _simple_ correlation coefficient or the _partial correlation coefficient_?

Comment: Neither: since you want to study the relationship, and you view $Y$ as a response to be related to regressors $X_i$, then perform multiple linear regression.